# Apply NetEM WAN delay on a docker container interface

Tags: networking, docker, iproute

I want to apply NetEm delay on the egress traffic of a docker container. Usually, I run:

```
# /sbin/tc qdisc add dev $INTERFACE root netem delay ${DELAY}ms
```

The issue is that I have no idea about the interface to which the container is connected to.

For example, I am running the following container:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine /bin/sh
```

and then I ping 8.8.8.8:

```
/ # ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=44 time=39.783 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=44 time=39.694 ms
```

What I want to do is adding the NetEm rule **from my host machine** and see changes to the ping time.

If I run `ifconfig`, I see that several **virtual ethernet interfaces** are present (since other containers are running), but I don't know which one is connected to the container I am interested in:

```
# ifconfig
veth09fa1c5 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 96:73:c9:15:93:b8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9473:c9ff:fe15:93b8/64 Scope:Link
          .....

vethf05ef93 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ca:ea:97:ef:cd:9d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c8ea:97ff:feef:cd9d/64 Scope:Link
          .....
```

I believe that I have to apply the NetEm rule to one of these interfaces. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The veth route seems less straightforward but I think it might be doable based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724225/docker-how-to-get-veth-bridge-interface-pair-easily).

However, by default (using the bridge interface) the requests from and to your container virt interface will be going through the default bridge network interface `docker0`.

You could setup the NetEm rule there, but it would slow down all your other containers too. If that's an option, running your container on a separate network (create with `docker network create`) would be a cleaner way to do this for experimentation/testing.

```
docker network create slownet 
docker network inspect slownet
[
    {
        "Name": "slownet",
        "Id": "535e40d880716a27efe1fd3fada62bdc4d9fa13bde09279de650fa53f13f7cdd",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
ifconfig
 .... 
br-535e40d88071 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:4E:B6:F8:C2  
          inet addr:172.19.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:4eff:feb6:f8c2%32727/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:14368 (14.0 KiB)  TX bytes:16888 (16.4 KiB)
.... 

# so br-535e40d88071 is the interface
```

Let's spin up the container and start ping:

```
host> docker run -ti --rm --net=slownet alpine sh    
container> ping 8.8.8.8 
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=114 ttl=37 time=0.251 ms
```

And then add the NetEm rule:

```
host> tc qdisc add dev br-535e40d88071 root netem delay 100ms
```

When that happens I see the increase in latency:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=115 ttl=37 time=0.693 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=116 ttl=37 time=101.086 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=117 ttl=37 time=104.056 ms
```

Comment: I think it's a clearer option to apply netem on a separate docker network with respect to a veth. Thanks.