# how to see the pod and veth relationship in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

is there anyway to see the relationship of kubernetes v1.15.2 pod and veth? now I could see the veth in host but do not know which pod owned.

```
vethe4297f4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        ether ba:01:db:4a:7d:d0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9999796  bytes 1671107011 (1.5 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9231477  bytes 2153738950 (2.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethf059d46: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        ether 6a:8f:a3:65:dd:4c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11724557  bytes 5581499446 (5.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12847645  bytes 2142367255 (1.9 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethf9efebf: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        ether fa:c7:76:53:4a:36  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11103657  bytes 2587046474 (2.4 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8993500  bytes 1816804215 (1.6 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

by the way, I am learning the flannel communication procedure from the architecture :

[image]

Comment: do we talk about standalone K8s or managed solution (GKE, etc) ?  Which CNI is used? Am I right that it is  Flannel?

Comment: yes,it is flannel, standalone k8s deployment by myself

Comment: "is there anyway to see the relationship of kubernetes" -- there is. I've been axperemating a lot with it today. Will share results tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there anyway to see the relationship of kubernetes v1.15.2 pod and veth?

TL;DR :
Yes.
There is a [bunch of similar topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724225) on StackOverflow and even some [scripts on Github](https://github.com/micahculpepper/dockerveth).

## Explanation:

There is a  [very good article](https://dustinspecker.com/posts/how-do-kubernetes-and-docker-create-ip-addresses/) on Kubernetes (K8s) networking.

Oversimplified, "K8s networking" handled by Linux’s network namespaces and virtual interfaces.

Below console output has been taken on my GKE cluster, but shall be applicable to standalone cluster as well.

```
$ sudo ip link show | egrep "veth|docker" | awk -F":" '{print $1": "$2}'
3:  docker0
5:  vethcf35c1bb@if3
6:  veth287168da@if3
7:  veth5c70f15b@if3
11:  veth62f193f7@if3
12:  vetha38273b3@if3
14:  veth240a8f81@if3

sudo docker ps --format '{{.ID}} {{.Names}} {{.Image}}' "$@"  | wc -l
25
```

As you can see, I have 6 `veth`'s  serving traffic for 25 docker containers. Let's find the `veth` that serves traffic for one of the pods.

```
$ kubectl get pods 
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
server-go-7b57857cfb-p6m62   1/1     Running   0          7m41s
```

1. Lets find the docker container id for the pod.

```
$ sudo docker ps --format '{{.ID}} {{.Pid}} {{.Names}} {{.Image}}' "$@" | grep POD_server
6aa1d952a9f3 k8s_POD_server-go-7b57857cfb-p6m62_default_02206a28-42e1-43a5-adb8-f6ab13258fb1_0 k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1
```

2. Checking a `pid` for it:

```
$ sudo docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' 6aa1d952a9f3
4012085
```

3. Allowing system tools accessing the namespace of that `pid`:

```
$ sudo ln -sf /proc/${pid}/ns/net /var/run/netns/ns-${pid}
```

```
#in my case the commands were :
$ if [ ! -d /var/run/netns ]; then sudo  mkdir -p /var/run/netns; fi
$ sudo ln -sf /proc/4012085/ns/net /var/run/netns/ns-4012085
```

```
$ sudo ip netns exec "ns-4012085" ip link show type veth | grep "eth0"
3: eth0@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default
```

4. Checking  exact interface that serves traffic for the container.

From that output (`eth0@if14`) we can say that the `eth0` for the `6aa1d952a9f3` docker container is linked to the interface `14:  veth240a8f81@if3`  on host machine.

Based on this example you can write your own script to match `veth` interfaces to Pods, containers, etc.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for this thread, very useful.
I got the desired output using nsenter.
So instead of tweaking the files, just do

```
sudo nsenter -t 4012085 -n ip link show type veth | grep "eth0"
```

Worked at least for me ;-)

Comment: This only gives the interface on the container side, not its peer on the node.